# Simulate header click in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to simulate a headerclick in datagridview column 1 with shortcut keys but I dont know how.

```
Private Sub frm_lista_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.S And e.Alt Then
    'this handler exists  
    DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(whathere, whathere)
  End If
End Sub
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the form has this property set:

```
Me.KeyPreview = True
```

Since you are trying to specify column 1 from a keyboard event, you can pass your own event arguments:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
  If ((Control.ModifierKeys And e.Alt) AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.S) Then
    Dim mea As New MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.None, -1, -1, -1, -1)
    Dim dgvcme As New DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs(1, -1, -1, -1, mea)
    DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(DataGridView1, dgvcme)
  End If
End Sub
```

The event should now have the `e.ColumnIndex` property set.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
  If e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("OK")
  End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could just call a sub-routine from both places:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
  If ((Control.ModifierKeys And e.Alt) AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.S) Then
    Call HandelColumnOneClick()
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
  If e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
    Call HandleColumnOneClick()
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub HandleColumnOneClick()
  '// Do Something
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Lars. My keydown handler already works as expected but problem is in DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick where I have this: Dim col_index = e.ColumnIndex and this generate exception if I send "Nothing" to handler. So it seem's that I should send something 'more defined' than "Nothing". I would like to send click to column header "1".

Comment: However, I try this: Dim f As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs
            f.ColumnIndex = 1
            DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender, f) but f is readonly so is here a way or workaround to send f.columnindex to DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick handler?

Comment: Thank you very much for so wide and helpful answer which works as expected. DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(DataGridView1, dgvcme) transfers e.ColumnIndex properly.